# Twitter bootstrap typeahea - get value and id

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i try to get a value and the id from this data-set.

Gettin one think is easy, but i dont know how i can get the second information?

Importang to know is, that in my site can be a dynamicly number of input fields wich all have to use this function.

This is the JS Code

```
// Datas
  var datas = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: function(d) { return d.tokens; },
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      remote: {
          url: 'autocomplete.php?s=1&li=5&query=%QUERY',
          wildcard: '%QUERY' }
    });

$('#orga_id').typeahead(null, 
        {
          name: 'orga_id_autosuggest',
          displayKey: 'desc',
      input: 'value',
      highlight: true,
      hint: false,
      limit: 5,
      minLength: 2,
      wildcard: '%QUERY',
      source: datas.ttAdapter(),
      templates: {
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile([
          '<div class=\"media\">',
                '<div class=\"pull-left\">',
                    '<div class=\"media-object\">',
                        '<img src=\"{{img}}\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\"/>',
                    '</div>',
                '</div>',
                '<div class=\"media-body\">',
                    '<h4 class=\"media-heading\">{{value}}</h4>',
                    '<p>{{desc}}</p>',
                '</div>',
          '</div>',
        ].join(''))
      }
    });
```

And in the html form something linke this

```
<input type="text" name="3_orga_name[]" class="form-control autosugbtn" value="" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="3_orga_id[]" value="">
```

Thats the Feedback of the PHP File

```
$results[] = array(
          "value" => $res['DS'],
          "desc" => $res['ORG_NAME'],
          "img" => "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/?" . (rand(1, 10000) . rand(1, 10000)),
          "tokens" => array($query, $query . rand(1, 10))
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get more than one values from your dataset, you have to transform your result set and return a key-value pair. So in the example below, the `response` is a JSON string that I receive, and then I get all the values I need.

> A friendly reminder to everyone who are still using Twitter-Typeahead
>   is to move away from this repository as it is no longer maintained.
>   Instead redirect yourself to [corejavascript/typeahead.js](https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js) which is
>   a fork of the original repository, and the same author (@JakeHarding)
>   maintains this repository.

**I am using v0.11.**

**HTML**

```
<div id="prefetch">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Countries">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    var tags = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function(datum) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.name);
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: {
            url: 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/js/data.json',
            cache: false,
            transform: function(response) {
                return $.map(response, function (tag) {
                    return {
                        name: tag.tagName,
                        id: tag.tagId
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    $('#prefetch .typeahead').typeahead({
        minLength: 3,
        highlight: true
    }, {
        name: 'tags-dataset',
        source: tags,
        display: 'name',
        templates: {
            suggestion: function (data) {
                return '<p><strong>' + data.id + '</strong> - ' + data.name + '</p>';
            }
        }
    })
    .bind('typeahead:select', function (ev, suggestion) {
        console.log(ev);
        console.log(suggestion);
        $('#your-id').attr('value', ev.id);
    });
```

Here is a working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xzrh7fde/) example to get you started.

Comment: @4usolutions Your question was not that clear, but I have made an attempt to answer your question. If this is not what you needed, reply to me and we will see your issue.

Comment: Hi, how and at wich position I can get access to the "tag.name" and work with it? And how i can make it that the one variable "tag.name" is display in the search-input file and at same time the "tag.id" is put in a hidden input file?

Comment: @4usolutions You should be able to use the values `name` and `id` normally in your `templates -> suggestion`. E.g.` "<div id='" + data.id + "'>" + data.name + "</div>"` which should produce `<div id='id123'>name123</div>`. Keep in mind that `data` is passed to the suggestion function like I have shown in my example.

Comment: oh, i want to use this not in the template of the drop-down box, i need this in the final form. I try again to explain: I select a entry for example "Testname", this should display in the seach-input field. The "Testname" has a "ID", this ID i want to put into a hidden field of the form after "Testname" is selected.

Comment: @4usolutions Okay got it. What you need is the events of typeahead. Once you select something, typeahead will fire an event. You can handle that event like I have done in my updated example and then do whatever you need to do. That being said, I don't remember whether `ev` or `suggestion` will have your data. Just print everything and figure out where the data is.

Comment: @4usolutions Checkout these other events as well. https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events

Comment: Hi, thanks, we are close the the finish ;-), If i try to do this "alert('test value:'+ev.value);" as a part of the "blind"-function i cannot access them - What i do wrong?

Comment: @4usolutions Can you just print `ev` and `suggestion` and see what you get. If this still exists, I will try it on my end.